# What is the '_u' data type in this #define declaration?

Tags: c, preprocessor-directive

Hope I'm phrasing this question correctly... I have begun working through some coding examples for a [*micrcontroller device*](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples), and I see many expressions similar to the following:

```
#define REG_CONFIG _u(0xF5)
```

I *think* this preprocessor directive declares that `REG_CONFIG` is a constant of type `unsigned int` and value `0xF5`. What I don't understand is the use of `_u(value)`; `_u` is apparently a data type but AFAIK, it's not a standard type (like `unsigned int`). I'm also under the impression that data types are declared as a *suffix* instead of a prefix.

Could someone explain this to an inexperienced programmer?

Comment: `_u` is most likely some macro which is taking 0xF5 as an argument, and is unrelated unrelated to the `_u` data type you found.  If it is related to unsigned at all, maybe it adds a suffix to the literal like `#define _u(N) N ## U`. Or a cast  like `#define _u(N) ((unsigned) (N))`. You won't know until you find it.

Comment: The context doesn't indicate that `_u` is a type; `_u(0xF5)` would be a syntax error. There's nothing in standard C called `_u`. It must be defined somewhere else in the project. Try searching for `#define _u`.

Comment: the way to find where it is defined is to add "#define _u xxxx" in your code. The preprocessor will tell you: "error,  _u previously defined here xxxxx.h:yyyy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a macro defined to conditionally add a `u` suffix to the literal to give it unsigned type. The macro seems to be used so that headers containing macros with such literals can be reused for assembler sources which don't support the `u` suffix.

See a github search [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/search?q=%22define+_u%22) resulting in the following snippet from one of multiple possible `platform_defs.h` headers:

```
#ifndef _u
#ifdef __ASSEMBLER__
#define _u(x) x
#else
#define _u(x) x ## u
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for that... I had looked at every `#include`d header file referenced in the source file, but apparently `platform_defs.h` is a `#include` in one of the header files that's listed in the source file. The macros you've listed are a reasonable solution for accommodating both C & Assembler I suppose, but I wonder if there's a "clearer" way to do this? Different point, but it might add a bit of clarity to your answer if you mentioned `platform_defs.h` in your answer?

Comment: @Seamus I don't know a better alternative. It already seems pretty minimally invasive.

Comment: I guess you're correct on that - but I *still* don't see how any of the `platform_defs.h` files find their way into [this source](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/blob/master/i2c/bmp280_i2c/bmp280_i2c.c). :P. [Another search](https://github.com/search?q=%22platform_defs%22+repo%3Araspberrypi%2Fpico-sdk+extension%3Ah&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=&l=) didn't help.

Comment: @Seamus I didn't actually try to verify that the file is included. There is probably some platform-specific configuration in the build system which will one way or another result in one of the `platform_defs.h` being chosen and included.

Comment: But if the file were **NOT** included, wouldn't I get errors at compile time? IOW, I'm sure the compiler gets to it, but I can't see how. But that wasn't part of my question, so I'll drop this line of inquiry.

Comment: Further details can be found [here](http://www.tentech.ca/2010/11/pre-processed-assembler-and-c-integer-literals/).

Answer (score 0):

According to this github PR comment: https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/pull/127#discussion_r660001009

> Yeah, we use `_u(3)` or whatever in the SDK in case the constant is included by assembly, which doesn't understand `3u` - i.e. we define `_u` to either suffix `u` or not based on where we are.

Comment: Good catch on the comment - now we understand where it came from!